# Shop Woocommerce for 3 types of sweatshirts with different prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I wanted a plugin or script that would automatically add specific attributes to each new product. If I am going to put 300 designs for tshirts, if each tshirt has 20/30 variations (color, size, design color), it will take me many months to add 250/300 products. Can you automate the attributes every time I add a product?

Best regards

Comment: WooCommerce Import Products, create the attributes and variations before hand and then write out your spreadsheet and import, easy peasy.